# Spacewalk/Cobbler system with multiple interfaces/MAC

Tags: pxe-boot, interface, mac-address, cobbler, spacewalk

I have bare metal provisioning set up with a DHCP/PXE server and a Spacewalk server.

I'm using cobbler system records to match a machines MAC address to the system profile.

Basically:

```
 cobbler system add --name=example --profile=example --kickstart=/var/lib/cobbler/kickstarts/example.ks --mac=00:00:00:00:00:00
```

The problem is the bare metal machines obviously have multiple NICs and I do not want to worry initially how the remote hands will plug them in.

My question is how do I register a cobbler system with multiple interfaces/MAC?

Comment: Yes I'm aware - I want to register multiple mac addresses to the one cobbler system record. Sorry if my question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done to get around this is to first add the system with any interface and then edit the system to add more interfaces.

```
cobbler system add --name=system2nics --profile=example --kickstart=/var/lib/cobbler/kickstarts/example.ks --mac=00:00:00:00:00:00


cobbler system edit --name=system2nics --interface=eth1 --mac=50:50:50:50:50:50
```

It's not an ideal solution but does what I need to achieve.